# Make variable accessible like window

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

Lets say I have one variable `var car = 'VW'` in `index.html`

`index.html` is the binding of my application, from there I access several modules:

```
   <script>
    var car = 'VW';
    var Initializer = require('./js/initializer');
    Initializer.check_requirements();
   </script>
```

Now in `initializer` I try to access this variable what does not work.

```
var Initializer = {
check_requirements: function(){console.log(car)};
};

module.exports = Initializer;
```

However when I attach the variable `car` to `window`:

```
window.car = 'VW';
```

Then Im able to access it in my module over `window.car`;

**How do I create an global variable `car` that I can also access in my modules, so that I do not have to attach to `window`?** 
Thanks

Comment: How exactly is this related to node.js?

Comment: I concur, this looks like a `commonJS` question.

Comment: Retracted my close, agree with the comments - apologies if I was trigger-happy.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think there's another way to register a global variable other than attaching it to the global object (which is `window` on the browsers)

Answer (score 2):

In a browser context, a "global" variable is in fact a property of the `window` object, which acts as the global context. The syntax you have in your question, a bare `var` statement in a script tag in an HTML page, will in fact add that `var` name as a property to the window. However, since you're using what looks like a CommonJS `require` statement here, which is not natively supported in most browsers, there's probably a compile step you're not including in your question that's preventing this from working the way you expect.

However, the short answer is, **don't do this** if you can avoid it. Most applications of global variables are better accomplished with parameters, e.g. `Initializer.check_requirements(car);`, or in a separate module storing configuration settings, or other approaches.